# problem in setting up amd dual graphics Trinity [Radeon HD 7660G] and Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]

Tags: graphics, radeon, fglrx

I am having problem in setting up AMD dual graphics Trinity [Radeon HD 7660G] and Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series].
Trinity is working fine.
I am unable to switch to my Thames graphic, amdcccle showing them as unknown display.

this is the output from lspci

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7660G]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
```

I have installed fglrx using following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
```

This is output for fglrxinfo

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7660G
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005
```

Please help me if there is some other way to switch the graphics or I need to install something else.

I have observed that my xorg.conf file is getting changed as I am restarting the system.

When I ran

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

the content of file was

```
$ cat xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[1]-0" RightOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[1]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[1]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[1]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[1]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[1]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection`
```

But when I restarted the system and found no effect, then I checked the file again.
This the content which is different from earlier.

```
$ cat xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 1"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection
```

So content is getting changed on restart. what to do :(

Comment: If some one know the solution please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to see if there is anything in the xorg.conf file and if not use:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

It might be picky about aticonfig vs. amdconfig.

Restart and check BIOS to make sure the cards are enabled. When loading, if the screen freezes on the load screen hit Alt + Ctrl + F2, login and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

To see if both GPUs are now in the config file. If they are still not there, you can put your second GPU in there manually by using the info provided by:

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

Just write or copy and paste a second copy of what is in xorg.conf below what is there and replace the details in the second copy with the info about your other GPU, i.e 01:00.0, and Default 1

If it's a bad install and it says fglrx doesn't exist, then go to:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide

and make sure to do a for sure uninstall  and then download all of the prereqs. and install again.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD is also an awesome resource. I would suggest bookmarking them two links, and reading everything.

```
aticonfig --help
```

is cool too.

---

The little reply box is not cool

per the cchtml website,
Force use of the new xorg.conf (if necessary)

> Some people find that changes to xorg.conf don't get used by the
>   driver. To force the ATI driver to adopt changes made to xorg.conf,
>   use the following command:
>
> sudo amdconfig --input=/etc/X11/xorg.conf --tls=1

I have used that before, in 12.04, and since 12.04.4, it seems harder to set up the proprietary drivers. I got mine set up, but it was a pain. I can do dual-gpus, but I have to set my BIOS to default GPU, and auto Integrated. But, I have a APU and a GPU, not two actual GPUS, so maybe that is harder to set up in bios?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
After running aticonfig the same issue persists.
The content of /etc/X11/xorg.conf is
`Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 1"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection
`

Comment: I have updated the question with my findings and content of xorg.conf file. As it is getting changed after restart.

Comment: I'd try first to go into the Catalyst Control Center and see if after clicking on Display Manager if you get a pop-up saying Catalyst has setting that need to be changed Click apply. If it doesn't try sudo amdconfig --input=/etc/X11/xorg.conf --tls=1 in the terminal and restart.

Comment: No I am not getting any pop ups while clicking Display Manager.
Even apply and default buttons are disable there. I can only click ok and cancel.

Comment: I have also done the force one as you suggested but still it is getting changed at restart :(:(

Comment: It's a pain, I know! The only other thing I can think of is sudo aticonfig --intial , without adapter=all and going into CCC after reboot, and click the Display manager hoping for a popup. I hope you get it working, but mine are, but my BIOS might be different, so I got the option so set it in Bios and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by a bug on gpu-manager, reported here: [Bug #1310489 “xorg.conf overwritten by booting system”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489)

There are two possible workarounds:

a) Edit /etc/init/gpu-manager.conf commenting out lines until it looks like this:

```
#start on (starting lightdm
#          or starting kdm
#          or starting xdm
#          or starting lxdm)
task
exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```

b) Remove the ubuntu-drivers-common package:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-drivers-common
```

After either a) or b), you should generate your xorg.conf again:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

Finally reboot, xorg.conf should no longer be overwritten.

Source of solution: [My xorg.conf gets overwritten on reboot - ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220552). Thanks to the people over there.